# console log success message when promise resolves in promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code

```
async function a() {
   return await someAsyncStuff();
}

async function b() {
    return await anotherAsyncStuff();
}

async function execute() {
   return await Promise.allSettled([a(), b()]);
}
```

What i'd like to add is some logging when one of the promises resolves.

Is this the correct way?

```
async function a() {
   return await someAsyncStuff().then(() => console.log('function a success'));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to retain the value that the asynchronous call returns? Right now this `then` will *only* log and discard any potential value. But if you want to keep the result, you can.

Comment: @VLAZ yes retaining is probably not the most important, but I just want to know where exactly to add this logging part.